# Is it possible to run ganglias gmetad and ganglia-monitor not demonized on debian?

Tags: debian, monitoring

I wonder is it possible to run ganglias gmetad and ganglia-monitor not demonized, under my own user (me, sudo) on debian? Because while `gmond.conf` contains something like `demonize` option I see no such in `gmetad.conf`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`man gmetad`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gmetad), you'll probably find

```
-d, --debug=INT
Debug level. If greater than zero, daemon will stay in foreground. (default='0')
```

so using commandline argument, e.g. `gmetad -d 1`, should do the trick.